# Is is possible to deactivate the Lightning port?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, lightning

On a current iDevice, such as an iPhone 6 or an iPad Air 2, is it possible to deactivate the Lightning port?  I don't want to break it, just temporarily disable it, similar to how `Settings > Bluetooth` can be used to temporarily disable Bluetooth.

Edit: Why?  To prevent data exfil in an enterprise setting.  So I'm looking to prevent data sync and data transfer.  Charging is still ok.

Comment: to what end? Stop it from charging, stop it from syncing, connecting as a data port...?

Comment: Exfiling data, so stop syncing and data transfer.  Good question; I should have included that in my OP.

Comment: You can edit your question.  FWIW I do not know of a way to do that, but it would be an excellent security feature.

Comment: interestingly, if you plug it to a Win machine, you get the option to 'trust'. No trust == charging only. idk of any Mac equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

No, any version of iOS doesn't allow the deactivation of the Lightning / 30-pin port.

Plugging an iOS device into a new computer will prompt a message on the device whether or not to "trust" that computer or not. "Trusting" a computer allows normal access, otherwise the device would only charge and disallow any data transfer... although it seems in your environment that would be of little benefit.